Help identifying an episode from an old sci fi tv series
Ok, this is a long shot but here we go:
I remember watching an episode of an old (60's or 70's) sci fi tv series as a kid, in which a man and a woman are stranded on a planet, inhabited by 3 aliens (not entirely sure about the number), one of them at least can render himself invisible.
The man and woman are shapeshifters, the man changes into a dog at one point and the woman into a bird. She is also captured by one of the aliens.
That's pretty much all I can remember, I might have some details wrong, as it was a long time ago, but for some reason it has left a very vivid impression on me. I have done quite a bit of google research about it but no luck.

Sounds like the Space: 1999 episode The Rules of Luton from 1976 (Season 2, Episode 8), but only the woman shapeshifts.

Whilst Koenig and Maya are exploring a planet called Luton,which is lush in vegetation, she picks a flower and he helps himself to some fruit. As a result they are put on trial for murder by three talking trees, the Judges of Luton. The trial is by combat and the pair must face three aliens, one with superstrength, one which can render itself invisible and one which can teleport. 

Maya is a Metamorph and capable of turning into any living thing. During the episode, she changes into a bird and also a dog (to pick up the scent of the invisible alien). Here it is:




Yes, this is it, you have my eternal gratitude, sir :) so it seems I did get some details wrong after all.
